# Error updating Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint

I consistently (several weeks already) get the error:

```
Unable to connect to mozart.ee.ic.ac.uk:http:
Failed to fetch [package name]
```

I am Using Linux Mint 19.3

Every time I do a `apt-install` (anything) or apt update (with and without `sudo`) it starts running, downloading several items until it gets to the `mozart` site, where it hangs for a while and then gives up.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mirror seems to be buggy, open your sources.list then replace the first repository url with a working one e,g:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
```

then replace the url `http://mozart.ee.ic.ac.uk` with `http://mirror.pit.teraswitch.com/linuxmint/` like this:

```
deb http://mirror.pit.teraswitch.com/linuxmint/ tessa main upstream import backport
```

The list of available mirrors ([at the bottom of the page: Repository mirrors](https://www.linuxmint.com/mirrors.php) ).

Comment: Thanks for that. The suggested urls did not actually work, got lots of errors on it, but I was not aware of this repositries list. Now when I did a google search on it, I found a working list, copied/pasted and voila, all good! The page that helped is: https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/sources.html

Answer (score 1):

I replaced the entire contents with this, and it works great:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyssa main upstream import backport
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
```